# Ignore white spaces in printing

Tags: c, string

I have a code to read a line from a file input. My goal is if a line is a blank (either, \n \t or spaces), skip the line and continue to the next line. I have a problem on doing this. My code worked if the line is only an "enter key [\n]", however, if the line consists of just \t (tab) or spaces, it does not work. Here is the code. Can somebody help me how to ignore if the line is completely whitespaces? Thank you

```
while(!feof(input)){

    fgets(word,1000,input);

    if((strcmp(word,"\n")==0) || (strcmp(word,"\t\n")==0) || (strcmp(word," \n")==0)){
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: you can refer D & R c programming book similar question is given I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isspace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) in loop:

```
int is_whitespace(char *word) {
   size_t spaces = 0;
   size_t i = 0;
   size_t slen = strlen(word);

   for (i = 0; i< slen; i++)
       if ( isspace((int)word[i]) ) spaces++;

   return spaces == slen;
}
```

and then you would be able to:

```
while( fgets(word,1000,input) ) {

    if (is_whitespace(word)) 
       continue;
}
```

Also, the loop condition is wrong. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

---

As suggusted by @chux, it can be simplified and the call to `strlen()` can be avoided:

```
int is_whitespace(char *word) { 

   while (isspace((unsigned char) *word))
     word++; 

   return *word == 0;
   }
```

Comment: Yes. It includes all the whitespaces. Manual says: *checks for white-space characters.  In the "C" and "POSIX" locales, these are: space, form-feed ('\f'), newline ('\n'), carriage return ('\r'), horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v').*

Comment: Sorry @blue Moon but it still ignores the line that only consists of \t (tabs)

Comment: It worked now! thanks. I forgot to exclude the return statement in the for loop. Thank you!

Comment: Could simplify to `int is_whitespace(char *word) {  while (isspace((unsigned char) *word)) word++; return *word == 0;`.  BTW `(int)` serves no value.

Comment: @chux Yes, that looks simpler, avoiding the call to strlen().

Answer (score 1):

```
char ch;
if(1 != sscanf(word, " %c", &ch)){
    continue;
}
```